# Displaying Ubercart order history for customers in their "my account" page

Tags: views, ubercart

I currently have a small store set up with Ubercart where customers can purchase the items I have listed. They go through the process of purchasing and then receive an order confirmation email. On this email their is a link to "Check Order Status". That is what I want however, when the link is clicked they are taken to their "My Account" page and nothing is displayed.

**Question:** Because Ubercart gives this link I assume their is some sort of information that can be displayed (ie order history/status). Is their an area in the configuration that I can insert the information or is it even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after long last, by accident, I found the option. In Drupal 7 go to Home » Administration » People and select the permissions tab. Once there navigate down the "Orders section" within that section you will be given the option to allow users to view certain order information. Select the relevant information and you are good to go. Be careful not to give them access to things they should not be able to see (these options are also available there as well).

Answer (score 2):

Log into Drupal7. From there goto Home >> Administration >> People >> select the permissions tab.

In that Order title, if u want to give particular role like(buyer) then u need to provide "View own orders" permission alone for that role(buyer). That will display his orders alone. It will displayed in the my account(user) link, there will be a tab called as orders.

There is also other thing which is "View all orders" which will display all orders of all buyers(role) in the site.It should be enabled only for administrator.